# The AdS in AdS/CFT correspondence is really a class of spacetimes which asymptotes to a subclass of spacetimes with the same causal structure as AdS

Tags: quantum-gravity, ads-cft, partition-function, anti-de-sitter-spacetime, asymptotics

On page 131 of [these](http://www.hartmanhep.net/topics2015/gravity-lectures.pdf) notes, a precise formulation of the AdS/CFT correspondence is given by the GKPW dictionary

$$Z_{\text{grav}}[\phi_{0}^{i};\partial M] = \langle \exp \left( - \frac{1}{\hbar} \sum_{i}  \int d^{d}x\ \phi_{0}^{i}(x)O^{i}(x) \right) \rangle_{\text{CFT on } \partial M},$$

where the LHS is the gravitational partition function in *asymptotically* $AdS_{d+1}$ space.

---

However, the metric is defined by coordinates

$$ds^{2} = \frac{\ell^{2}}{z^{2}}(dz^{2}+dx^{2})$$

on *Euclidean* $AdS_{d+1}$.

---

I fail to see how an *asymptotically* $AdS_{d+1}$ space is compatible with an *Euclidean* $AdS_{d+1}$.

Is the metric

$$ds^{2} = \frac{\ell^{2}}{z^{2}}(dz^{2}+dx^{2})$$

for Euclidean $AdS_{d+1}$ just what the asymptotically $AdS_{d+1}$ spacetime *asymptotes to* at the boundary?

Comment: Do you have any reason at all to suspect the answer to this is not just "Yes."? Physics.SE questions should be potentially useful to a broader audience, we are not a tool to check your understanding of every slightly unclear passage you read in a paper.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will keep this in mind. Should I delete my question?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain further what your confusion is? Are you worried that by changing the signature of the metric you have a space with very different causal structure?

Comment: @ gj255 That's exactly my point of confusion.

Comment: yes. $AdS_{d+1}$ have negative signature for time coordinates. And by wick rotating we go the Euclidean time. We can see there is no $i$ in the partition function' exponential.  So they are the same except one coordinate is wick rotated. So asymptotes must be the same.